# How to check when connection is established, if minecraft player's session is valid as original player?

Tags: java, minecraft

I challenged myself to create a minecraft server with the proviso that most of the plugins I will use will be just mine. I have already made many different plugins from shops to various minigames. Now I have decided **to code my own login registration plugin**. Basically **everything is already functional** and ready, but **I would like to add one feature there. This feature is that when a player connects to the server (warez), my plugin checks the player's session to see if it is original **(I mean that player have bought game and he is logged throught original mojang launcher with valid mojang session. Players should connecting to server in warez mode (not logged in, using not official launcher))**.** I don't just mean the name as mentioned here, but his mojang session. In short, whether it is logged in via the original launcher with its e-mail and password.

**I absolutely don't know how verifying the originality of players works**, I know that mojang has an API but I don't know if it offers such a possibility. I would also like to know if the client is sending a hash from the UUID or sessionID to the server, which can be compared with the mojang API, or I don't know.

***UPDATE:***

I found these two articles:

**1)** https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Login

**2)** https://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption#Authentication

From this articles I roughly understood that during the connection of the client I will send the server ID and ciphers together with the server and then the subsequent hash on which they will agree will send the client via POST to the mojang servers and my server should then ask from the mojang if it is logged in on my server the client.

**UPDATE2**

I thought of the following:

1. If I programmed my own proxy in the phenomenon to which players would connect and this proxy would reproduce everything to the server. Thus, I would be able to let in who I would like to go and I can also do cross-checks via the mojang page with the server ID and hash. But it would be 3-rd party software, it would not be a plugin.
2. Modify the spigot itself, by that I mean do the above somewhere at the SSLServerSocket level, where the spigot server receives all the socket and the data from them. There, if I code the bridge over which the data would pass, I am also able to agree with the client SERVER ID, calculate a hash and verify it from the mojang server. But it would still not be within the plugin but in the servers.
3. Override some of the deep parts of the server mentioned above from the plugin. The plugin would replace some parts of the server after loading.

Now my questions is, how to replace some mentioned parts of the server from plugin? Is good idea to try use reflection (i am noob, with reflection) and replace some functions with my functions, that would calling back to spigot low level code?

**Thank you very much for any advice.
Have a nice day.**

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What do you mean with `original`? How else should the player log in?

Comment: Hi, i mean that player have bought game and he is logged throught original mojang launcher with valid mojang session. Players should connecting to server in warez mode (not logged in, using not official launcher). #Added this to post

Comment: Test if the UUID of the player matches the UUID od the username of the player? See https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/check-if-player-is-premium-and-check-session.339771/

Comment: I dont know how it works with UUID, when player is not logged into mojang then will his UUID be a random generated and dont match with mojang UUID?

Comment: I have no idea from minecraft but it seems like this.

Comment: I found this https://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption#Authentication, from this article I roughly understood that during the connection of the client I will send the server ID and ciphers together with the server and then the subsequent hash on which they will agree will send the client via POST to the mojang servers and my server should then ask from the mojang if it is logged in on my server the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isCracked(ProxiedPlayer player) {
   
    String name = player.getName();
    UUID actualUUID = player.getUniqueId();
    String actualUUIDStr = uuid.toString();
    String offlineUUIDStr = getMd5("OfflinePlayer:"+name);
   
    if(offlineUUIDStr.equals(actualUUIDStr)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

// Taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/md5-hash-in-java/
public static String getMd5(String input)
    {
        try {
 
            // Static getInstance method is called with hashing MD5
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
 
            // digest() method is called to calculate message digest
            //  of an input digest() return array of byte
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());
 
            // Convert byte array into signum representation
            BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
 
            // Convert message digest into hex value
            String hashtext = no.toString(16);
            while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
            }
            return hashtext;
        }
 
        // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding comment to your answer to explain it and make it more usefull

Comment: I think the code is already commented pretty well. And when CooderSK has already created multiple plugins, this code won't be to hard to understand.

Comment: @CooderSK Could you please accept my answer if it worked.

Comment: @FishyCode sorry I cant, I dont have enough reputation to vote it